# moving info between function in class

Tags: python

I want to write a function that holds all the strings that the user insert to argument `plays` in function `move()`, to the string `undo_str` in the function `undo()`.
what am I missing here?

```
class Sokoban:
        def __init__(self, board):
                self.board = board.copy()

        def move(self, plays):
             ............

        def undo(self):
                undo_str=""
                undo_str=undo_str[:]+plays
                self.undo=undo_str[:-1]
```

Comment: Where is `plays` defined in `undo`?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, could you example start and end states so we can see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the user insert a string to the function move(="plays").
I want to copy the string and add  it to the string called "undo_str" in the function undo.

Comment: Then simply make `undo_str` an instance attribute and append to it in `move`. i.e. add `self.undo_str = list` and change all reference of `undo_str` to `self.undo_str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this helps. If you add a few more class attributes to hold on to information it should be fairly easy. Here the init method would initialise sokoban.plays and sokoban undo_str as empty strings. sokoban.move('string') would change sokoban.plays to 'string', and sokoban.undo_str() would add the current sokoban.plays to sokoban.undo_str

```
class Sokoban:
    def __init__(self, board):
            self.board = board.copy()
            self.plays = ''
            self.undo_str = ''

    def move(self, plays):
         self.plays = plays
         ............

    def undo(self):
            undo_str=undo_str[:]+self.plays


sokoban = Sokoban(board)
sokoban.move('play1')
sokoban.undo()
sokoban.move('play2')
sokoban.undo()

In: sokoban.plays 
Out 'play2'

In: sokoban.undo_str
Out: 'play1play2'
```

(note that I got rid of the line 'self.undo = self.undo_str[:-1]'. this would conflict with the function self.undo)

Comment: tnx!
now if I want the undo function insert the string to "plays", how I can do that?

Comment: I do not completely understand your question, but I think that I have given enough help in understanding how python classes work that you can probably work out the specific solution to your task on your own.